# How to read SQL server schema info in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How can I know in C# the list of Tables in database.

The list of columns each tables has with complete specification like column one is Id and it has data type of int(50), etc

Comment: no. Just wondering how to do that

Comment: Try reading documentation first.

Comment: Yes. Reading the documentatio nis not obtional. here is a whole chapter in there exactly about how to do that - in the sql server documentation that is.

Comment: Related: *[Can I get name of all tables of SQL Server database in C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005095/can-i-get-name-of-all-tables-of-sql-server-database-in-c-sharp-application)*

Comment: you can get all table names from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464195/read-schema-name-table-name-and-column-name-from-a-sql-db-and-return-to-c-sharp/8464270#8464270

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [GetSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366.aspx) method of the [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class:

```
DataTable t = _conn.GetSchema("Tables");
```

For more info read the MSDN article *[Retrieving Database Schema Information (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcax58fh.aspx)*. Note that this will get you the results without having to write or directly pass/execute any SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Use the information schem views

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Thy are the "standardized way to look at that and contrary to the sys tables quite guaranteed not to change (while the sys.* tables are an implementation detail).

Answer (score 1):

We have previously used [SQL Server Management objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) with good success. SMO allows you to interact with the SQL Server quite easily thorugh C#. You just need to reference some DLLs and use the object model provided by them. For example, to list the tables you can use the foreach to iterate over the Database.Tables -property.

Codeproject has an article which goes through the basics: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMODemo.aspx

Comment: Nice article it is.
Sure it will help me.
Being a beginner need some time to digest all the stuff