# getting Schema of one Table in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to get Schema for a table with name "Petro" in SQL SErver
after initializing connectionString, I use this Code

```
conn.open();
conn.getSchema("Tables");
```

but it returns schema for all the tables.  I only want the Petro schema. What should I do?

Comment: MS SQL Server? Or another type of sql server?

Comment: database is in SQLServer

Comment: Here is an answer: [Ado.net Getting the schema for a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173834/ado-net-getting-the-schema-for-a-table)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read SQL server schema info in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550549/how-to-read-sql-server-schema-info-in-net)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
string[] restrictions = new string[4];
restrictions[2] = "Petro";
DataTable table = conn.GetSchema("Tables",restrictions);
```

Look here for more information: [MSDN: Working with the GetSchema Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254934%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Edit: use GetSchema instead of getSchema

Comment: This code will return only 1 row with the name of the table. If it is needed to get a full table schema (all columns with their types) the code should be the following: `conn.GetSchema("Columns", restrictions);`

Comment: this returns only table property not table field.

Answer (score 8):

You can retrieve the schema in following way:

```
            string sql = "select * from Petro WHERE 1 = 0";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

Comment: Do you really want to Select * on Petro just to get the schema?  It looks like the cmd.ExecuteReader adds a lot of un-needed overhead to this.

Comment: As OP has not mentioned any column name in the question except table name, I have answered on the basis of that...

Comment: Hate to admit it (6 years later) but this was the only code which worked for me...

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server solution:

There is a store procedure called `sp_columns`. When you run that procedure with the table's name as a parameter, it will return the schema just for that table.